# My wallet has been compromised, how can I transfer all remaining funds to another wallet

Tags: myetherwallet, private-key

Some scammers managed to get hold of my Private Key and trashed my wallet, using an automatic script.
They didn't get hold of everything, because there was not enough Ethereum in it for paying gas prices.
Is there a way that i can quickly transfer the remaining tokens to another address?
If I have to transfer them one by one it will probably take too long, since i am guessing that as soon as some ETH reaches that wallet they will run that same script again.

Comment: That's an interesting question. The first answer that comes to mind is - No. But then again, if the remaining of your tokens there were worth the cost, then I believe that those private-key hijackers would have added some Ether to your wallet and transferred them out of it by now. So common sense tells me that whatever is still there is probably not worth the cost.

Comment: There is an article that explain how some tokens were recovered from a compromised wallet https://medium.com/mycrypto/operation-cryptokitty-rescue-93fd8e00e4f8